# show that $3^{1974} + 5^{1974} \equiv 0 \bmod 13$

Tags: proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

show that $3^{1974} + 5^{1974} \equiv 0 \bmod 13$

My attempt with this question was to use Fermate Little's THM. But I do not understand how to properly use it for this question. Can some one show me a proof.

Comment: What is $1974\pmod {12}$?

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to use FLT.

\begin{align}
3^{1974}+5^{1974}&\equiv (3^3)^{658} + (5^2)^{987} \pmod{13}\\
&\equiv (27)^{658} + (25)^{987} \pmod{13}\\
&\equiv 1^{658} + (-1)^{987} \pmod{13}\\
&\equiv 1 -1 \pmod{13}\\
&\equiv 0 \pmod{13}\\
\end{align}

Comment: I prefer the orthography flt for the little one. :-)